# Change Mysql prompt

Tags: mysql

Having just

```
mysql>
```

Listed as my command location is not useful.  Sometimes I log in to a live server to pull data off to use in my local machine.  Today I *almost* started trying to modify live data after I had dumped it to my local machine and not switched back.

How can I change the command prompt so it would say something like I get at the linux terminal so it says:

```
greeds@localhost>
```

or

```
admin@remote-name>
```

depending on whether I am local or remote respectively?

I am not a db admin just a C++ dev who wants to be safe when editing data.

Comment: A simple search for "mysql prompt" returns the help page from mysql https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-commands.html

Comment: I searched SO for an answer and not finding one asked the question.  Most google searches list SO at the top of the answers anyway.  But thanks for the link.